# How to force user to enter a different number each time in a given range in Python?

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

My question is related to book "Starting Out With Python" (3rd Edition) by Tony Gaddis. It is Chapter 7 Question 11. Let me excerpt question for reference, **then explain my question below that**.

> The Lo Shu Magic Square is a grid with 3 rows and 3 columns. The Lo Shu Magic Square has the following properties: •
>   The grid contains the numbers 1 through 9 exactly. • The sum of each
>   row, each column, and each diagonal all add up to the  same number.
>
> In a program you can simulate a magic square using a two-dimensional
>   list.  Write a function that accepts a two-dimensional list as an
>   argument and  determines whether the list is a Lo Shu Magic Square.
>   Test the function in  a program.

**MY QUESTION: Basically, I am asking user to populate this 3x3 grid by using numbers 1-9. However, each number should be different from each other. How can I force user to enter a different number each time in a given range (which is 1-9)? Is there a special function for that? After finishing my "Lists" chapter, I am not capable of doing this in Python.**

I am also providing my code for this question if it helps any. As of now, user can enter any number, even two-digit etc. Thank you in advance.

```
# lo shu magic square

ROWS=3
COLS=3

def main():    
    # create the two dimensional list
    square = [[0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0]]

    for r in range(ROWS):
        for c in range(COLS):
            square[r][c]=int(input("Enter a number 1-9 (can't enter the same number again): "))
```

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. Most of what you've written in your question is irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create new list and add every user input in that list. Then, you can check if he already entered input. Example:

```
inputs = []
while True:
 inp = input("Enter something: ")
 if inp in inputs:
  print("Please, enter something else! You already entered that!")
 else:
  print("Successfully entered!")
  inputs.append(inp)
```

Example that you can use in your case:

```
numbers = []
while True:
 inp = int(input("Enter number from 1 to 9: "))
 if 1 <= inp <= 9 and inp not in numbers:
  print("Success!")
  numbers.append(inp)
 else:
  print("Your number is already entered or isn't in range 1-9. Please enter again.")
```

Edit: You already store user inputs in list. You can just check if new input is in your list.

Comment: Thank you. I will work on this now. It is a really good strategy. Never thought storing inputs in a list. Thanks.

Comment: I updated answer, it is more close to your example now.

Answer (score 2):

Math is your answer friend:

```
print 1 <= x <= 9
```

If I misunderstood your question, please let me know!

---

**@edit**: see comments

```
square = [[0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0]]

entered = [];

for r in range(3):
    for c in range(3):
        v = int(input("Enter a number 1-9 (can't enter the same number again): "))
        if v > 9 or v < 1 or v in entered:
          print("bad number")
        entered.append(v)
        square[r][c]=v
```

Comment: Hi I think you did. So this is a two-dimensional list. I am asking user to populate. It is not about print function, it is about input function I think. For example user entered 1 for square[0][0], but he/she should enter a different number for square[0][1] etc.until all 9 elements are filled out.

Comment: I believe I understood that part. I'll append an example.

Comment: I realize that I didn't check for uniqueness as you originally asked. Check out the latest revision with the `v in entered` bit.

Comment: Thanks. But still does not prevent user from entering the same number again. He can populate all 3x3 grid by the same number (1-9).

Comment: I think you typed that right as I updated, check again friend :)

Comment: Oh. I see now. Yes it gives me "bad number" when I enter the same number. but it still records on the list. Let me show my output:                                               
    [[1, 3, 3], [2, 4, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

Comment: I left `print("bad number")` for you to replace. You could use `sys.exit()` or have them start over, or re-enter the number, whatever you'd like. I just gave you an example of detecting it, which is what you asked for.

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry I wasn't aware. Thanks I will build on this. Appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see whether a number is already in the square by comparing each value in each row with the new value.

```
>>> square = [[0, 1, 9], [2, 5, 3], [6, 0, 4]]
>>> new_value = 7
>>> any(value == new_value for row in square for value in row)
False
```

This uses the builtin function [**`any`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any).

Or, you could check for containment using `in`:

```
>>> 3 in [1, 2, 3]
True
```

So:

```
>>> any(new_value in row for row in square)
False
```

Comment: Thank you. I am testing out all of the perfect suggestions here. Will try yours next. Best.

Answer (score 1):

You'd simply check to see if it's in the square, I'd guess.

```
for r in range(ROWS):
    for c in range(COLS):
        entered = int(input("Enter a number 1-9 (can't enter the same number again): ")
        existing = True in [entered in row for row in square]
        if not existing:
            square[r][c]=entered
```

If that's inefficient, try having an entered list, and check for the existence in there. I'll leave it to the hardcore guys to determine the efficiency of this approach